# Prevent group rename in Outlook 2013 in VSTO Addin

Tags: outlook, vsto

I am developing a VSTO addin in Visual Studio 2013 for Outlook 2013.  I add my own group to a few of the ribbons, such as the Home tab in Explorer view.
I would like to prevent anyone from renaming my group.  Users can use the Customize Ribbon feature in Outlook to manage groups and commands and I can easily rename, move, or remove the group by customizing it.
Is there a way I can attach to an event and prevent the user from renaming my group (I would prefer to be able to prevent them from removing/hiding my group too).
I have looked through the Outlook 2013 Object Model list and I cannot find any relevant events to attach to.  I don't see any Group objects or anything that looks relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can attach to an event and prevent the user from renaming my group

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) nor the Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.

You may consider hiding the button in Outlook (on the backstage UI) for showing the options dialog instead.

Comment: Not supported, OK.  As to your second comment, if I did that, my addin would be useless.  The whole point of my group is to provide three buttons that perform various tasks.  It wouldn't be much use if that's in the backstage or options area.  It's kind of a silly request, preventing rename of a group, but thanks for the first comment.